# How long does it normally take to set up a test node? How much of your disk is utilized?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, testnet, ubuntu, storage-footprint

I did a complete factory reset on my computer and simply started over. I have a Aorus 5SE with windows 11. I am using VirtualBox 7.0.6 and Ubuntu 20.04.

My new virtual machine has 4GB of base memory, 4 CPUS, and the optical drive has 95GB. The equivalent of dynamic space adaptation is functioning. (I was recommended by my teacher to use 2GB, 2 CPUs, and 60 GB)

Before using "$sudo snap install bitcoin-core" and letting my computer run over night, "df" indicated my '/' directory had 15% of memory used. However, the default system information that prints at start up indicated 13.5% of 45.64GB for "/". This confused me since I don't recall configuring that number, nor the ability to change it.

[image: initial df result]

This morning, my computer somehow went to sleep but the download appears to still be running, just very slowly. The session information indicates 0% guest activity and 50-75% VMM load of CPU usage. The results of "df" indicate 89% usage of my " / " directory.  I ran it again after some time and the usage increased by 92 1K-Blocks. Is this abnormal?

[image: results of "df" after running installation of bitcoin-core]

[image: session information]

Comment: Hi Culler, I assume that you are trying to synchronize with testnet, but you never actually state what you are doing. What are you trying to achieve? Do you need a complete copy of the blockchain or just a node that’s synchronized? How is your node configured?

Comment: Hi Murch, yes I am trying to synchronize with tesnet in order to participate in my Digital Currency Programming class. The next step in class is writinge python script to interact with the tesnet.

I believe I do need a complete copy of the testnet or at the minimum a node that is synconrized. My instructructions were to use snap package using "$ sudo snap install bitcoin-core" which was successful and then "$ bitcoin-core.daemon -testnet -daemon" which never completes for me. I don't think my node is configured yet since it hasn't been successfully initialized yet after installation.

Comment: @Murch please see my comment above, I forgot to tag you.

Comment: Okay, let’s find out how far your synchronization has progressed: What does `bitcoin-cli -testnet getblockchaininfo` return?

Comment: @Murch from my ssh link, "bitcoin-cli: command not found" unfortunately.  Im not sure if that is because it is still trying to sync or not.

Comment: @Murch However, I started over without "-daemon" and I am at 42% storage usage, block height 1258686 if that is of any help. I probably shouldnt have stopped. Maybe I just need to run a full node. Idk...

Comment: Testnet is currently at a height of 2'419'347, so you’re at about half the height.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.